# How use long instead of int can bulletproof the following method - Effective Java

Tags: java

Consider the following code picked from Joshua Bloch - Effective Java, page 263

```
// Broken - requires synchronization!
private static volatile int nextSerialNumber = 0;
public static int generateSerialNumber() {
    return nextSerialNumber++;
}
```

> One way to fix the
>   generateSerialNumber method is to add
>   the synchronized modifier to its
>   declaration. This ensures that
>   multiple invocations won’t be
>   interleaved, and that each invocation
>   will see the effects of all previous
>   invocations. Once you’ve done that,
>   you can and should remove the volatile
>   modifier from nextSerialNumber. To
>   bulletproof the method, use long
>   instead of int, or throw an exception
>   if nextSerialNumber is about to wrap.

1. I understand that we can remove `volatile` after we make generateSerialNumber `synchronized`, as it is redundant. But, does it make any harm? **Any performance penalty if I am having both synchronized and volatile like**

---

```
private static volatile int nextSerialNumber = 0;
public static synchronized int generateSerialNumber() {
    return nextSerialNumber++;
}
```

---

1. What does, *use long instead of int* means? **I do not understand how this bulletproof the method?**

Comment: `long` is the 64-bit integer format, while `int` is 32-bit. These integer types usually overflow without any warning - but it will take 2^32 times the iterations to overflow a `long` than to overflow an `int`.

Comment: @Jean Hominal, Oh. I thought bulletproof in the sense of threading. Understand!

Comment: It is really a tad confusing that the author added it to a paragraph that was mainly about synhroization.

Comment: and yes, there may be a performance penalty for using both volatile and synchronized.

Comment: volatile has significantly less performance hit than synchronized. (it also does less)

Comment: @Peter - actually, that's not really true.  since it was strengthened in jdk 5 (it has exactly the same memory semantics now), its performance impact is fairly similar to synchronized.

Comment: @jtahlborn, see my answer for my reply.

Comment: You must be writing a really really small program to worry about whether incrementing an long is so much slower than an int.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It simply means that long will hold many more numbers than int.

> or throw an exception if nextSerialNumber is about to wrap

implies that the concern here is that you run out of numbers and you end up with an overflow. You want to ensure that does not happen. The thing is, if you are at the maximum integer possible and you increment, the program does not fail. It happily goes not incrementing but the result is no longer correct.

Using long will postpone this possibility. Throwing the exception will indicate that it has happened.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have answer on 'Any performance penalty if I am having both synchronized and volatile like'?

Comment: It should be noted that 2 billion serial numbers is a lot. If you're generating one a second, you've got over 60 years worth. Use a `long` instead of an `int` and you've got enough to cover nearly 300 thousand years even at a burn rate of 1 million a second. Even with a burn rate of 1G/s (good luck on achieving *that* any time soon!) you're still looking at over twice the currently-believed maximum human lifetime. Let's have some perspective here!

Comment: I have actually seen it happen in the logging tables of a legacy application ~10 years old.  Trust me, you **don't** want to be the guy on that midnight support call.  Incidentally, we "fixed" it by resetting the counter to 1.  The old data had long since been archived.

Comment: @Donal, using an integer just seems like asking for trouble.  If one per second = 60 years, then 60 per second (entirely reasonable) = 1 year.

Comment: @Peter: And if your ID lifetime is a few minutes, you're *still* fine with that.

Comment: @Donal touche - i guess it all comes down to the fact that we all have different expectations of what the typical ID will be used for...

Comment: @Peter: To be fair, I usually just whack in a random UUID. That, despite being *very* fat, has the advantage of making it possible to merge IDs across systems.

Comment: I occasionally like to pause and give thanks that I work in an age where we rarely have to worry about saving one or two bits anywhere we can, like they used to back in the days of vacuum tubes.

Answer (score 2):

> What does, use long instead of int means?

It ensures that serial numbers don't roll over for a long, long time to come. Using an `int` you might use up all the available values (thus `nextSerialNumber` will have the maximum possible int value), then at the next increment the value is silently rolled over to the smallest (negative) int value, which is almost certainly not what you would expect from serial numbers :-)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO volatile/AtomicInteger is faster than synchronized in a multi-threaded context. In a single threaded micro-benchmark they are much the same. Part of the reson for this is that synchronized is a OS call whereas volatile is entirely user space.

I get this output from the following program on Java 6 update 23.

```
Average time to synchronized++ 10000000 times. was 110368 us
Average time to synchronized on the class ++ 10000000 times. was 37140 us
Average time to volatile++ 10000000 times. was 19660 us
```

I cannot explain why synchronizing on the class is faster than a plain object.

Code:

```
static final Object o = new Object();
static int num = 0;

static final AtomicInteger num2 = new AtomicInteger();

public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    final int runs = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
    perfTest(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
                synchronized (o) {
                    num++;
                }
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "synchronized++ " + runs + " times.";
        }
    }, 4);
    perfTest(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
                synchronized (Main.class) {
                    num++;
                }
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "synchronized on the class ++ " + runs + " times.";
        }
    }, 4);
    perfTest(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
                num2.incrementAndGet();
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "volatile++ " + runs + " times.";
        }
    }, 4);
}

public static void perfTest(Runnable r, int times) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(times);
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        es.submit(r);
    es.shutdown();
    es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.println("Average time to " + r + " was " + time / times / 10000 + " us");
}
```

Comment: did you try changing the run order?  also, did you do some warmup runs before tracking that totals?  lastly, the average is not necessarily the best measure of performance.  micro benchmarks are hard (i'm sure you are aware of this).

Comment: also, going by the last 2 numbers, the volatile call is half as expensive as the sync call.  so, using volatile with sync makes the operation 50% more expensive.  seems to verify my initial statement.

Answer (score 0):

One way of bulletproofing would be (in addition to the above)

if (nextSerialNumber >= Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    // throw an Exception;

or print out something, or catch that exception in calling routine